# Run automation on headless browser in an ec2 instance with Amazon linux

Tags: amazon-web-services, selenium, amazon-ec2, webautomation

I have an automation framework that uses static html pages within its project directory to perform certain aws operations such as dynamoDB scan and Aws Lambda executions. Due to some performance bottleneck in a dependent api component for the test we are trying to move the framework to an ec2 instance with Amazon linux and run the tests from there.

Since we have methods in the TestNG class that actually uses selenium web driver to spin up a browser and open up the static page in order to perform the required Aws operations I am pretty sure this test is going to run into issues.

There are two potential approach I see for solving this issue:

1. Implement AWSUtil classes and use necessary aws clients to replace the web dependent logics (Will require some effort and re-engineering)
2. Use a headless chrome browser (or any compatible one) in order to run the web dependent steps.

I am pretty sure that number 1 can be easily achieved, just a matter of time and effort. However, would love to know if there is an easy way of accomplishing #2 since this would not require any code rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

We got the same issue and been successful with puppeteer,

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer

If you don't want to install the latest version of node, you can dockerize your tests.

puppeteer can run headless or with browser.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have a standalone framework using TestNG and Java. How would this integrate with that and run fine on AWS EC2 using amazon linux. Could you provide more detailed steps?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to change anything in your tests, just the setup and the execution. The tests can run headlessly on a Continuous Integration (CI) server. There is no out-of-the-box setup since there is no display output for the browser to launch in. However with Xvfb you can launch the browser virtually. Straight from the docs:

> Xvfb (short for X virtual framebuffer) is an in-memory display server for UNIX-like operating system (e.g., Linux). It enables you to run graphical applications without a display

Depending from do you want to keep Xvfb running in the background until the process is killed, there are two options:

```
Xvfb :99 &
export DISPLAY=:99
run-your-tests-here
```

or

```
xvfb-run run-your-tests-here
```

Here is a [Linux tutorial](http://elementalselenium.com/tips/38-headless). I am using this for my Docker based Jenkins setup and works like a charm, every time.